# Establishing impact force from deceleration data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, acceleration

I am trying to establish an impact force. The impact came from a spear (wooden with a stone tip) hitting a soft (meat) target. The acceleration was measured by a GCDC X400-2 accelerometer.

Due to the spear impacting a non-consistent fluid/solid target, the deceleration was not regular. This is the reason I do not know how to apply the F=ma formula that is clearly the one need here.

I need to establish the amount of force with which the spear impacted the target and the amount of energy that was dissipated throughout the impacting into the target.

I was thinking about using the energy in momentum formula, but this goes into relativism, which is beyond me.

Below is the acceleration data for the impact. It is inverted, due to accelerometer mounting position:

`Time   m/s^2
31.721039   -5.568076923
31.726013   -12.8724359
31.731018   -23.52961538
31.736023   -22.93089744
31.741028   -15.62653846
31.746002   -2.394871795
31.751007   4.67
31.756012   -3.472564103
31.761017   -9.878846154
31.766022   -14.54884615
31.770996   -21.97294872
31.776001   -21.61371795
31.781006   -12.33358974
31.786011   -7.005
31.791016   -9.998589744
31.79599    -8.920897436
31.800995   0.838205128
31.806  18.56025641
31.811005   81.30589744
31.81601    173.3887179
31.820984   153.9902564
31.825989   49.87320513
31.830994   7.364230769
31.835999   -38.19820513
31.840973   17.06346154
31.845978   138.0044872
31.850983   75.13910256
31.855988   -12.21384615
31.860993   -3.771923077
31.865967   123.455641
31.870972   229.1892308
31.875977   149.44
31.880982   26.58307692
31.885956   -15.32717949
31.890961   0
31.895966   -17.00358974
31.900971   -20.65576923
31.905976   0.478974359
31.91095    -3.233076923
31.915955   -0.538846154
31.92096    -5.268717949
31.925782   -12.51320513
31.930786   -10.29794872
31.935791   -4.610128205
31.940949   2.45474359
31.945954   -3.652179487
31.950959   -10.59730769`

The average velocity of this spear in flight was 13.89 m/s. This was calculated as the average velocity from the time of release to the time of impact. This throwing distance was 5m and the flight time was 0.36s. There was no deceleration noticed during this flight time.

For reference, this is for a PhD in Archaeology and hence I am not the best at physics in the world!! If there is any more information that you need, please contact me and I will be happy to provide it (along with larger data samples if that would help. I cropped the data to keep this post smaller.)

Cheers!

Comment: What archaeological question are you trying to answer? Impact *force* might not be the best measure of what you are trying to quantify. The amount of *energy* which was dissipated is probably a better measure; this is the kinetic energy of the spear, $K=\frac12 mv^2$ where $v=13.89m/s$.

Comment: The best you can do is _average_ force over a time step. Actual peak force requires a lot more detailed modeling to get to.

Comment: What is the mass of the target and the mass of the spear.

Answer (score 0):

What seems interesting is the maximal force that the target undergoes. Using Newton's third law, you only have to know the mass of the spear, and its acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

The force during the deceleration is not constant, but the instantaneous force is the acceleration value multiplied by the mass. The acceleration peaks at $a=229\mathrm{~m/s^2}$. Multiply this by the mass.

You could take the mean acceleration over the time interval 3.80 .. 3.88 s, which is about $\overline a = 72~\mathrm{m/s^2}$. The velocity change in this interval is $\Delta v = \overline a \cdot \Delta t = 5.8~\mathrm{m/s}$, which is quite a bit lower than the flight speed that you state (13.9 m/s), so either the spear went straight through the target and continued flying, or your accelerometer was broken.

For the `performance' of a spear, momentum transfer is probably a better metric than force, peak force, or kinetic energy. Momentum transfer can be expressed in various ways: $\Delta p = m\Delta v = F \Delta t = m\overline a \Delta t$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the acceleration data to get change in speed over change in time

[image: fig1]

I see a $$\Delta v = (4.99)-(-0.92) = 5.91 \;{\rm m\, s^{-1}}$$ over a time of $$\Delta t = (31.886)-(31.801) = 0.085\;{\rm s}$$

Take the translating mass $m_{\rm target}$ of the target where the accelerometer is mounted and convert the change in speed into an impulse (unit of momentum change)

$$ J = m_{\rm target} \Delta v $$

The change in momentum relates to the *average* force applied as

$$ F_{\rm average} = \frac{J}{\Delta t} $$

Now to find the peak force, we see there are 3 peaks of similar magnitude, and we can estimate the impulse of each peak $J_i$ as well as the time each peak lasted $\Delta t_i$

Fitting a basic cosine wave on the bounce data you will find the peak force for each peak as

$$ F_i = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{J_i}{\Delta t_i} $$

Using these formulas, and an example target mass of $70 {\rm kg}$ I get the following values for peak force

[image]